# Raspbian screensaver fails with VNC on Pi4

Tags: pi-4, display, vnc

I have activated the screensaver on Rasbian. I have the raspberry 7" touch screen. All works well manually, switches screen of after a certain amount of inactivity and comes on again when the screen in touched.
The issue is, when I access the Pi with VNC, it switches on the screen (good) but it never switches it off after inactivity.

Is there a fix for this?

NOTE: When I say screen saver I really mean the screen blanking setting in RAsperry Pi configuration->Display

Comment: "Raspbian" ... on a pi 4? I thought it became "Raspebrry Pi OS" ... and, well, which version

Comment: Apologies, its currently Bullseye. A sort of fix was to use Xscreensaver although this still leaves the backlight on.
Also it seems matchbox-keyboard  and Onboard have been removed from its repository which is annoying of you have a touch screen so may have to try bookworm.